# React Native VSCode Debug on M1

Tags: react-native, apple-m1, vscode-debugger

Is there an updated list of what to check when attempting to set up a VSCode React-Native development environment in an Apple M1?

I can run code, I just can't seem to debug it in VSCode.

This even gives me an error.  Thoughts on where to start?

xxxxx  (master)

```
$ npx react-native doctor
⠇ Running diagnostics...error Reduce of empty array with no initial value.
TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at Object.getDiagnostics (/Users/xxxxx/Projects/DoneWithIt/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-doctor/build/tools/healthchecks/xcodeEnv.js:86:8)
    at /Users/xxxxx/Projects/DoneWithIt/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-doctor/build/commands/doctor.js:145:29
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at iterateOverHealthChecks (/Users/xxxxx/Projects/DoneWithIt/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-doctor/build/commands/doctor.js:135:51)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at iterateOverCategories (/Users/xxxxx/Projects/DoneWithIt/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-doctor/build/commands/doctor.js:168:70)
    at Object.doctorCommand [as func] (/Users/xxxxx/Projects/DoneWithIt/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-doctor/build/commands/doctor.js:170:41)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/xxxxx/Projects/DoneWithIt/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:190:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Comment: I think you are using an array but you are not adding the initial value of it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you made all necessary setup for M1 Mac;

https://dev.to/davidkou/develop-android-apps-using-react-native-setup-on-mac-m1-and-troubleshooting-38bj

Comment: Thanks . followed the link.  Second command already fails

`brew install --cask adoptopenjdk8
Error: Cask adoptopenjdk8 exists in multiple taps:
  homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8
  adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8`

Answer (score 0):

I just found this and it was because I had refactored/split the Android and IOS apps to be in separate directories.

The workaround is just to `touch Podfile`.